# Kwicks for jQuery different sizes

Tags: javascript, jquery, kwicks

I'm doing a vertical dropdown with Kwicks for jQuery: http://www.jeremymartin.name/projects.php?project=kwicks

Take A look at the markup:

```
<ul class="kwicks">
    <li id="kwick1">
        <div class="title">Title 1</span>
        <div class="item"><b>Item 1</b> Description 1</div>
        <div class="item"><b>Item 2</b> Description 2</div>
        <div class="item"><b>Item 3</b> Description 3</div>
        <div class="item"><b>Item 4</b> Description 4</div>
    </li>
    <li id="kwick2">
        <div class="title">Title 2</span>
        <div class="item"><b>Item 1</b> Description 1</div>
        <div class="item"><b>Item 2</b> Description 2</div>
        <div class="item"><b>Item 3</b> Description 3</div>
        <div class="item"><b>Item 4</b> Description 4</div>
        <div class="item"><b>Item 5</b> Description 5</div>
        <div class="item"><b>Item 6</b> Description 6</div>
    </li>
    <li id="kwick3">
        <div class="title">Title 3</span>
        <div class="item"><b>Item 1</b> Description 1</div>
        <div class="item"><b>Item 2</b> Description 2</div>
    </li>
    <li id="kwick4">
        <div class="title">Title 4</span>
        <div class="item"><b>Item 1</b> Description 1</div>
        <div class="item"><b>Item 2</b> Description 2</div>
        <div class="item"><b>Item 3</b> Description 3</div>
        <div class="item"><b>Item 4</b> Description 4</div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Javascript:

```
$().ready(function() {
    $('.kwicks').kwicks({
        min : 15,
        spacing : 9,
        isVertical : true,
        sticky : true,  
        event : 'click' 
    });
});
```

See it live here: http://jsfiddle.net/6xL5M/3/

As you can see, they have different content size, and for default, Kwicks for jQuery show all with the same Size, isnt there a way to make each one have his own height?

Thanks a lot in Advance.

Comment: Your example isn't clear enough.  The javascript is targeting .cardapio-open, however, that class name is no where in your dom.  Can you update this and even make a jsfiddle for this to highlight the problem more clearly?

Comment: Ok, I'm doing it right now, sorry sorry for the inconvenience.

Comment: Here you are: http://jsfiddle.net/6xL5M/3/

Comment: Your question is about having each li have their own height as opposed to the same height Kwicks give each li through configuration?  Can you visually show me what you would like the final result to be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how I Solved this:
http://jsfiddle.net/6xL5M/5/

I didn't use the Kwicks Plugin for that, just Simple jQuery, that basically is:

```
$(".kwicks #kwick1").click(function() { 
    $(this).animate({height: 4 * itemsize + titlesize +'px'}, 600, 'easeOutQuint');
    $(this).siblings().animate({height: titlesize +'px'}, 750, 'easeOutQuint');
});
```

Where **4** referrers to how many Items it have, **itemsize** is the Height of each item and **titlesize** is the height of the Title. It also reset the siblings to the Height of the Title.

Maybe it can Help Someone.

Thanks for your Support!

Answer (score 2):

I just spent time looking through Kwicks and working with code on my own sandbox in order to figure out how to make a list with different heights for each li (when not in active state).

The answer unfortunately is that the kwicks library does not support that.  I figured this out two different way.  First I looked at the API --- there is no configuration for this setting.  Second, I tried to get the result using CSS on top of Kwicks, however the Kwicks library does not regard any of my CSS in its calculations so elements end up sitting on top of other elements (wrong).

If you want that type of functionality you will either have to extend the Kwicks library or just write your own code that can do this.

Comment: Hmm, Thanks a lot for awensring me! I will see what i'm going to do.

Answer (score 2):

@richardaday's answer is correct (I'm the author of Kwicks, so... just trust me :p).

FYI, I've moved Kwicks to a new home today: http://devsmash.com/projects/kwicks. The docs for the old version that you're most likely using are at http://devsmash.com/projects/kwicks/1.5.1.  I highly recommend updating to the latest version though - there are known bugs in 1.5.x, and the overall experience with 2.x should be much better.

Please note that while variable-sized panels aren't yet supported, this doesn't seem like an unreasonable feature to add.  Feel free to open a feature request and I can start looking into the feasibility of it: https://github.com/jmar777/kwicks/issues

Comment: Thanks for your Answer, but, inst there a way to define the height of each active li? Thanks a lot again?

Comment: Sorry for the delay - just saw this.  Unfortunately, no.  I'm considering removing the fixed secondary dimension requirement in a future version. I need to think a little about the implications of that, but for now there's no way to do that.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I did it just with jQuery, without Kwicks and it worked very nice! I Will post soon the code here, Maybe it will help someone! Thanks